# Form submission issue IE9 + Ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, internet-explorer-9

I have a form that is served via Ajax from the server when a button is clicked.  It pops up in a jquery dialog.

```
<form onsubmit="hideModal();return getAJAX(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateUserNotes">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="20312">
    <hr/>
    <B>Flags:</B><BR/>
    <input type="radio" name="flag" value="none" checked> <img src="images/icons/grey_flag.png"> No Flag<BR>
    <input type="radio" name="flag" value="green"  > <img src="images/icons/flag_green.png"> Green Flag<BR>
    <input type="radio" name="flag" value="red" > <img src="images/icons/flag_red.png"> Red Flag

    <B>NOTES:</B><BR>
    <textarea name="usernotes" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Notes">
</form>
```

This is the code that my script sends back to display the form.  With the HR in there, the form will not submit when you click "save notes".  It does not throw a javascript error, it simply does not submit.

If I remove the horizontal rule the form submits 100% fine.

Anyone know what might be causing this?  It only appears to affect IE9.  I cannot replicate it in Chrome or Firefox or earlier versions of IE9.

I think it has something to do with IE9's strictness, but I can't figure out how the horizontal rule is messing anything up.

Comment: Did you try it with a proper space between the letters HR and the slash?

Comment: As a workaround, what happens if you move the hr outside the form (it is only hidden fields above it, so I guess it shouldn't affect the appearance)

Comment: this is Mike with a real account. Eric, I tried the space, no difference. asc99c, yes if you move the text out of the form it works. Adding it inside the form is what causes this odd behavior. The challenge is, this is not the only instance of this happening and on some things it is just the text next to radio buttons that fouls it up (it doesn't have to be HTML markup). In which case I can't as easily just move the text out of the form because I want it adjacent to the radio item. Thanks for the help, but I am hoping still for a more definitive answer of what may be happening. I suspect there